# Is Navigability correctly interpreted in this code?

Tags: oop, uml, composition, class-diagram

Let's consider `Book` class and `Chapter` class.

```
Class Book {
   private Chapter chapter;
}

Class Chapter {
}
```

**Statement 1**: If `Book` contains `Chapter`, this is a **composition**, since destroying `Book` would also destroy `Chapter`

**Statement 2**: Since `Book` is associated with and aware of `Chapter`, it can also be **navigability**.

So, are both statements correct, I know statement 1 is correct, but I am not sure if statement 2 is precise.

Comment: there is no link between the fact a relation is a composition or not and its navigability, so to look at their differences has no sense

Comment: @bruno But I don't understand how how they different.

Comment: In the same way length and color are different and cannot be compared, composition and navigability are different and cannot be compared. It is not possible to answer to the question `Difference between Navigability vs Composition UML class diagram` because, again, that question has no sense. Read Christophe answer to learn what composition is and what navigability is

Answer (score 2):

### There is composition and composition

The same term "composition" is used to refer to very different things:

- **[object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)**, which is an OOP technique,  making one object to be made (composed) out of several other objects and values.
- **[UML composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams)**,  which is a kind of association where one object can be part of maximum one composite object at a time, and the composite has the responsibility for the existence and storage of the component. So it's an exclusive ownership.

*By the way, the Wikipedia article is misleadingly incomplete about UML notation for object composition, at the date of this answer: it completely misses the point that object composition could implement a simple association*

### Your case is object composition

In your example, you use object composition, with a composite `Book` and a component object `Chapter` (hint: make it a container to get your example more realistic)

There is **no guarantee that it's UML composition**:  For example, if this code would be implemented in Java, a `Book book` could have a private `Chapter chapter`.  But some method of the `book`, say `getChapter()`, could leak the private `chapter` to another object.  Since java classes are reference objects, the chapter would therefore not be guaranteed to exist in at most one composite, which is an UML requirement for UML composition. Moreover, in such case, a chapter may survive a book.

**Advice:** unless you are sure of an exclusive ownership,  avoid UML composition.  In case of doubt, model a simple association.

### Navigability

[**Navigability**](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) is orthogonal to the kind of association.  Navigability exist for composition,  aggregation,  and simple association.  It means that you can easily move from the instance of one class to an associated instance of the other class.

In your case:

- You can clearly navigate from composite  `book` to a component `chapter` (as easy as `book.chapter`).
- However,  there is no evidence of a backward navigation: so when you have a specific chapter, without knowing the book in which it is included, it's not possible to find back the associated book.

Comment: Couple of typos....

Comment: @qwerty_so true. that happens when I answer late in the night and typed all the day...

Comment: Or when you get old and your fingers seem to have their own life when hitting the keyboard ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so ;-) indeed, that’s the case of inversion. But the cheap keyboard on my expensive macbook pro ages much faster than me. Some frequently used keys get very reluctant to behave well, that’s for the missings ;-) I sometimes wonder if we couldn’t have an algorithm for using these characteristics... wait! There is: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics

Comment: What bothers me more is that touch-bong-pad above which I accidentially hit when typing :-/ Well...